# WiX Burn Bundle Custom UI LaunchApprovedExe

Tags: wix, burn, wix3.10

I am using WiX 3.10 to create a bundle installer (Burn), I am writing a custom UI for it using WPF. I would like the installer to launch one of the installed executables. I've been trying to get the exe to be launched using LaunchApprovedExe having looked at [this WIP](http://wixtoolset.org/development/wips/3249-allow-ba-to-run-elevated-aync-process-through-engine/):

```
BootstrapperApplication.Engine.LaunchApprovedExe(hwnd, "CFDExeInst", "", 2000);
```

This finds the appropriate entry in the registry using the bundle.wxs entry:

```
<ApprovedExeForElevation Id="CFDExeInst" Key="SOFTWARE\CFD\CFDInst" Value="Loc" Win64="yes" />
```

And an entry in the MSI:

```
<RegistryValue Id="RV_CFLINST_LOC" Root="HKLM" Action="write"
               Key="SOFTWARE\CFD\CFDInst"
               Name="Loc"
               Value='"[INSTALLFOLDER]cfd.exe"'
               Type="expandable" />
```

However, I'm getting an error in the log file:

```
[0EEC:0BD4][]i600: LaunchApprovedExe begin, id: CFDExeInst
[0D54:0B84][]i601: Searching registry for approved exe path, key: SOFTWARE\CFD\CFDInst, value: 'Loc', win64: yes
[0D54:0B84][]i000: The executable path is not in a secure location: "C:\Program Files\CFD PAE\cfd.exe"
[0EEC:0BD4][]i699: LaunchApprovedExe complete, result: 0x80070005, processId: 0
```

The WIP says that Program Files is a secure location. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Value` of that registry key includes the double quotes around the whole path. It appears that the Burn engine does not ignore the double quotes. It should work if you remove them.