# Run cleanup with elevated privileges after uninstalling related bundle during upgrade

Tags: wix, bootstrapper, burn, wix3, wix3.11

I have a WiX 3.11-based bundle installer with a managed bootstrapper application.

I want to perform a cleanup action at the end of the installer, after removing a related bundle during upgrade. The cleanup action requires elevated privileges.

From what I understand, [the removal of related bundles always happens at the end of the install chain](https://support.firegiant.com/hc/en-us/articles/230912387-Bundle-chain-execution-order-), so I can't specify an `ExePackage` that will run after that. Is there any workaround here?

I can't run the cleanup action in the managed bootstrapper application process, since it is not elevated.

I've found [some people mention](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44856464/19045283) that it's possible to spin up a background process from the MBA that runs as administrator. That seems messy though, since I think it would cause a second elevation prompt (the first being at the beginning of the install execute phase). But it may be my only option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [`ApprovedExeForElevation`](https://wixtoolset.org/docs/schema/wxs/approvedexeforelevation/). It lets BAs launch elevated processes via the elevated engine process. See also [WiX Burn Bundle Custom UI LaunchApprovedExe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43660808/wix-burn-bundle-custom-ui-launchapprovedexe).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to this, it seems like it will solve my use case. For some reason, when I call `Engine.LaunchApprovedExe()`, it throws a COMException with a message of "The requested resource is in use. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800700AA)". The executable I'm trying to run is in the PackageCache. I verified that the registry key that points to the executable path is correct. Any ideas?

Comment: Realized my mistake - I was running `Engine.LaunchApprovedExe()` from my `ExecuteComplete` event listener, and I guess the engine is still active at that point. I'm now calling the exe from the `ApplyComplete` listener, and that is working correctly.